Why does dynamically updating terminal text in a for loop with an iterated value not output anything despite calling stdout.flush?
Representation of my current code below:
import sys

filelist = [file1, file2, file3]
totalfiles = str(len(filelist))
count = 0

for f in filelist:

    processdata(f)
    count+=1
    progress = f"Progress: {count}/{totalfiles}"
    print(progress, end="\r")
    sys.stdout.flush()

print("Complete")

Expected behavior is "Progress: 1/3" would appear in the terminal after the first iteration, changing to "Progress: 2/3" on the second and "Progress: 3/3" on the third. However, nothing appears until all iterations are complete, where "Progress: 3/3" is printed.
If I remove end="\r" from my print statement, it will print each of the expected strings on a separate line, which is what I would expect. Any suggestions on where I went wrong?

That should more or less work. What OS are you using? Is there anything else that you can think is relevant to your setup? If the flushing is delayed for some reason, then I would only expect to see Complete printed. Because your last Progress print will also contain a \r at the end. But that's not what you observe.

Perhaps, it's just executed quickly and you couldn't just see the progress?
How about trying to add some delay between loop to see each result as well as add flush=True?
import sys
import time

filelist = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']  # Replace these with your actual file variables
totalfiles = str(len(filelist))
count = 0

for f in filelist:
    # processdata(f)  # Ensure this is your actual data processing function
    count += 1
    progress = f"Progress: {count}/{totalfiles}"
    time.sleep(1)
    print(progress, end="\r", flush=True)  # Add flush=True here
    sys.stdout.flush()

print("Complete")

